# How to dynamically change the coordinates of views under the listview

Tags: android, xml

I have such xml:
[on screen](http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0004/0342/266582/150919/2b4a166abf.jpg)

I want to change the coordinates of layout "@+id/ifPopulate" every time when user will populate or remove items from listview (in other words, I want to have same distance between listview and layout @+id/ifPopulate").

And layout @+id/ifPopulate" don't have to be lower, than layout "@+id/buttons_at_the_bottom".

Here is my code. ListView's height need to be wrap_content,  of course. I wrote "100 dp" just for example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/blue_normal"
android:padding="10dp"
>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/ifSpinnerAddTextEdit"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ifPopulate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addItemNumTv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="@string/item_one" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addItemValEt1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addItemValBut1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/lview_top_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/lview_top_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ok" />

    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttons_at_the_bottom">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveCreateTemplateDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:onClick="getArrayProd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/save"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:onClick="getArrayProd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/back"/>

</LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One idea would be to translate x & y when the action happens or you could set absolute layout params on the view.